# Функцию, проверяющая, что элементы строки матрицы - простые числа в порядке убывания - работает не корректно

Tags: c, алгоритм

Написал функцию, которая проверяет, что элементы строки матрицы - это простые числа в порядке убывания (допускается наличие и не простых чисел, главное - что все простые числа по убыванию идут).

Однако, функция работает не корректно. Почему то не проходит проверка на увеличение счетчика. Почему?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int **a;

int simple(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=2;i<= n/2;i++)
        if( (n%i)==0 )
        {
            return 0; //не простое число
        }
    return 1; // простое число
}

int downsimple(int k, int m)
{
    int maxdigit, count;
    count = 0;
    for(int j=0; j++; j<m)
    {
        maxdigit= a[k][j];

        for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            if (1 == simple(a[k][i]))
            {
                count++;
                if(maxdigit < a[k][i])
                {
                    return 0; //не соотвествует условию
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Count %d\n", count);
    if(count > 0) { printf("\vse ok\n");return 1;} //в порядке убывания
    else {return 0;}
}

int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j;

    printf("The NUMBER of N:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    printf("The NUMBER of M:\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    a = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
     }

    free(a);
    printf("\n\nMemory free!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0; j++; j<m)` - опечатка тут у Вас. Остальное не проверял.

Comment: Ну, и в этом цикле `for(int i=0; i<m; i++)`, наверно должно быть `for(int i=j+1; i<m; i++)`

Comment: @andy.37, Да опечатка. Правда второго замечания не понял. Я думал, что он просто проходит заново все элементы поэтому сделал так. ПО аналогии, как сортировка пузырьком -  я беру элемент и сравниваю его с каждым, а потом опять тоже самое со следующим элементом. С Вашим кодом разобрался, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Почему сплошь и рядом решето до n/2, когда точное условие i^2<n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции `downsimple` внешний цикл:

```
for(int j=0; j++; j<m)
```

обычная опечатка (`for(int j=0; j<m; j++)` должно быть).

`maxdigit` нужно же только для простых чисел вычислять во внешнем цикле, разве нет?

Ну и внутренний цикл, вероятно, не от `0` нужно проходить, а от `j+1`.

В целом, алгоритм видится как-то так:

```
for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
   if (is_simple(a[k][i]))
      for (j=i+1; i<m; j++)
         if (is_simple(a[k][j]) && a[k][j] >= a[k][i])
            return 0
}
return 1;
```

П.С. да, и видеть j - индексом внешнего цикла, а i - внутреннего, как-то странно)))

Реализация с одним проходом по строке (без вложенных циклов):

```
int current;
// находим первое простое число
for (current=0; current<m && !is_simple(a[k][current]); current++)
    ;
for (int i=current+1; i<m; i++)
    if (is_simple(a[k][i])) // не простое число игнорируем
        if (a[k][i] > a[k][current])
            return 0; // следующее больше текущего - ошибка
        else
            current = i; // изменяем текущее
return 1; // вернет 1 если простых чисел нет вовсе.
```

Comment: Можно, конечно, все это одним проходом по строке сделать, я просто Ваш алгоритм модифицировал.